# I want to have two page.tpl.php on my site

Tags: theming

I want to have two page.tpl.php on my site ..one for my front page and other for rest of pages ...now both have same name page.tpl.php what should I do to make one of them for Front page and other for rest of pages

Answer (score 5):

To implement two templates files into a site.

By default, `page.tpl.php` already exists in a drupal theme.

Creating a front page template is rather simple. In your theme folder (sites/all/themes/), copy the `page.tpl.php` file from drupal core(e.g. garland) or your parent theme. Then rename it accordingly (see below). You probably won't see the results until you clear your cache; so make sure to do that.

`page--front.tpl.php`(drupal 7)

To do a custom front page that is mostly unique, yet merges seamlessly with Drupal, you can:

1. Create a file called `page--front.tpl.php` in your active theme directory.
2. Paste in solid, static HTML, with appropriate file path fixes.
3. Compare your page with the themes normal `page.tpl.php` and copy as much of the code tags as is logical into your new file in appropriate places.
4. You can put $content in the middle, sidebars in a useful place for you to call blocks into later, and the $footer in your footer zone, etc. Try to copy as much as possible - most of it can be useful, and is the real reason for using a CMS.

For more information regarding template files [Click Here](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656)